# ActiveRecord Postgresql Clear Connections Doesn't seem to actually clear them all the time

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, rspec, database-connection, connection-pooling

We're attempting a new mechanism for clearing out our db in between test runs, as we're having a hell of a time on Capybara tests with the [shared connection](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/470808) strategy.

Our basic idea with Postgresql is to create a snapshot of the db right after `db:test:prepare`. When then, in between feature specs disconnect the db, drop the db, re-create it from the snapshot and reconnect.

It seems to work *most* of the time, but there are a few test runs that somehow maintain the connection. Our setup looks roughly like this:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = nil
  end

  config.after(:each, type: :feature) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.clear_all_connections!

    `dropdb -Uroot our_apps_test_db`
    `createdb -Uroot -T test_template our_apps_test_db`
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['test'])
  end
end
```

What we've been finding however on some runs is that the rspec process is still holding onto a connection. If we peek into postgres connections just after the `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_all_connections!` like so:

```
puts `psql -c "select datname, application_name from pg_stat_activity;"`
```

At times (only a few) we see the following:

```
          datname           |                        application_name
----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 our_apps_test_db           | /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@influitive/bin/rspec
```

I'm wondering if there's anyone out there with a bit more knowledge about `ActiveRecord` and its connection handling than we have. We're rather stumped on this one.

Comment: Check when the connection was established. I wouldn't be surprised if what you have here is a race condition where something is *re-establishing* a connection between when you clear it and when you drop the db.

Comment: Why not just truncate? Is your app really changing the structure of the DB at runtime?

Comment: It doesn't change the structure no, but we do have seeded data requirements for our tests so truncation/seeding becomes slow. We're experimenting with that though. @craig I think you're likely right. Very hard to track down